# How to access an element value from one section to another section's element

Tags: orbeon

Let say I build a form with Form Builder with 2 sections.

I want the value of email-address element on section-1 control, can be displayed on section-2 section on show-email-address element.

How to do this with Form Builder?

Answer (score 0):

- insert a Calculated Value control
- open the Control Settings for that control
- enter a Calculated Value formula and set it to `$email-address`

*NOTE: This works whether you are in the same section or a different section, but it doesn't work across [*Section Templates*](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/section-templates).*

Comment: Thanks Erik. Any work around if I want to do this across section?

Comment: Do you mean across section templates?